# React no muestra nada

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, jsx

estoy aprendiendo con un proyento en ReactJS. el comando npm start ejecuta todo pero no renderiza nada, la pagina muestra solo el titulo de la pestaña (como si solo funciona el html y no reacciona el js o jsx), lo raro es que me sucedió de un día para otro[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/gianfrancomalzone/ReactJSMalzone34765.git). Adjunto el link de mi repo y dejo mi index. desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de revisar el repositorio de tu proyecto pude identificar el siguiente error:

Tienes un componente de nombre `ItemList` en cual intentar recorrer la propiedad `autoList` para mostrar los elementos de dicha lista

```
function ItemList(props) {
  return (
    <div> 
        { props.autoList.map((listaAutos) => {
        return <Card 
        key={listaAutos.id}
        titulo={listaAutos.titulo} 
        imagen={listaAutos.imagen} 
        marca={listaAutos.marca} 
        precio={listaAutos.precio} 
        stock={listaAutos.stock}/>;
      })} 
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

El detalle esta es que esa propiedad no se la estas pasando al componente y por ende aparece como `undefined` mostrando el siguiente error:

```
ItemList.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

---

Dicho error lo puedes corregir de la siguiente manera:

1. Empleando el hook `useEffect` en el cual vas a llamar a la funcion `getAutos` en la que se encarga de traer lo datos.
2. Asignar los datos del paso anterior a la variable `autoList` utilizando el hook `useState`
3. Pasar la propiedad `autoList` al componente `ItemList`

```
function App() {
  let estiloFondo = {backgroundColor: "#b398ff"};
  const [autoList, setAutoList] = React.useState([])
  
  // Aca llamar a la funcion cuando el componente se inicializa

  useEffect(() => {
    getAutos().then(data => {
      setAutoList(data) // Aca asignas los datos a la variable autoList
    }).catch(error => {
      setAutoList([]) // Aca igualas a un array vacio en caso de error
    }).catch(error => {
    })
  }, [autoList])

  return (
    <div style={estiloFondo} className="App">
      <CollapsibleExample/>
      <ItemList autoList={autoList}/> {/* Aca pasas la propiedad al componente*/}
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! despues de una limpieza de codigo dunciono perfecto. saludos